# application notifications stop after terminating application with task manager

Tags: android, notifications

I'm working on an application that registers a number of notifications for sessions during an event day , everything works fine , except when i use the task manager to terminate the application , it stops receiving the notifications , is there a way for the user to keep receiving the session notification even if application is terminated.

Comment: that is why you should not be using task manager apps. you killed the app so why would you think it would keep going like normal?

Comment: i'm testing the scenario if the user used application like "cleaner " that terminates a number of applications running in the background at once , and can't select separate applications to remove from memory

Comment: so tell you users if you want your app to work correctly stop using task managers, simple as that. It has been well documented that task managers do more harm than good

Answer (score 0):

This is the normal behaviour since android 3.1+. If you "force stop" an app, the notification will not be triggered anymore. More info :

Android 3.1 release note :

http://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-3.1.html#launchcontrols

http://commonsware.com/blog/2011/07/13/boot-completed-regression-confirmed.html